# Problems with Perspective Matrix

Tags: java, 3d

This is my first time trying to make a 3D engine. I'm having problems projecting points. Using the perspective matrix, I get some perspective, but it causes my points to [shift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7kKI.jpg) (should still be in the center of the screen). Any help is appreciated.

```
   public static Matrix getPerspectiveMatrix() {
   double far = 100;
   double near = 0.1;
   return new Matrix(
         new double[][] {
            {1,0,0,0},
            {0,1,0,0},
            {0,0,-((far+near)/(far-near)),-((2*far*near)/(far-near))},
            {0,0,1,0}
         }
      );
   }

   public static Point3D transformPoint(Point3D scale, Point3D rotation, Point3D translation, Point3D 
   point) {
     Matrix m = Matrix.mul(Matrix.getTransformationMatrix(scale, rotation, translation), 
     point.toMatrix());
     m.getArray()[0][0] = m.getArray()[0][0] / m.getArray()[3][0];
     m.getArray()[1][0] = m.getArray()[1][0] / m.getArray()[3][0];
     m.getArray()[2][0] = m.getArray()[2][0] / m.getArray()[3][0];
     return m.toPoint3D();
   }
```

Comment: what do `Point3D.toMatrix` and `Matrix.toPoint3D` do?

Comment: toMatrix returns a new matrix that is x, y, z, and 1 as a 4x1 matrix. Point3D is simply a class that contains an x, y, and z. toPoint3D takes a 4x1 or 3x1 matrix and takes the value in the first three rows and creates a Point3D object with those values as the x, y and z.